# ¿Cómo realizar un union all dentro de una subconsulta?

Tags: laravel, querybuilder, laravel-8

quiero hacer el equivalente a esta consulta SQL, que tiene un select anidado en una clausula where:

```
$sql="select p.nombre,p.apellidoPaterno,p.apellidoMaterno,p.genero,p.fecha_nac,p.pais_nac,p.direccion,p.correo,p.telefono,p.estado_civil,p.nivel_educ,p.profesion,p.foto,p.fecha_registro,p.hora_registro from persona AS p 
WHERE p.idPersona IN(SELECT eu.idEmpleado FROM empleadousuario AS eu UNION ALL SELECT us.idUsuario FROM usuariosistema AS us) and p.estado='A'";
```

tengo hasta el momento este codigo, pero por alguna razon me sale un error de sintaxis:

```
static public function TraerPersonas_US_EU()
{
     return self::from('personas AS p')
     ->select('p.nombre', 'p.apellidoPaterno','p.apellidoMaterno','p.genero','p.fecha_nac','p.pais_nac','p.direccion','p.correo','p.telefono','p.estado_civil','p.nivel_educ','p.profesion','p.foto','p.fecha_registro','p.hora_registro')
     ->whereIn('p.idPersona',function($query)
      {
         $query->select('eu.idEmpleado')->from('empleado_usuarios AS eu')->unionAll(function($builder)
         {
             $builder->select('us.idUsuario')->from('usuario_sistemas AS us');
         });
      })
      ->where('p.estado', 'A')
      ->get();
}
```

---

y el error que me muestra laravel es:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'union all (select `us`.`idUsuario` from `usuario_sistemas` as `us`)) and `p`.`es' at line 1 
(SQL: select `p`.`nombre`, `p`.`apellidoPaterno`, `p`.`apellidoMaterno`, `p`.`genero`,
 `p`.`fecha_nac`, `p`.`pais_nac`, `p`.`direccion`, `p`.`correo`, `p`.`telefono`,
 `p`.`estado_civil`, `p`.`nivel_educ`, `p`.`profesion`, `p`.`foto`, `p`.`fecha_registro`, `p`.`hora_registro`
 from `personas` as `p` where `p`.`idPersona` in ((select `eu`.`idEmpleado` from `empleado_usuarios` as `eu`) union all (select `us`.`idUsuario` from `usuario_sistemas` as `us`)) and `p`.`estado` = A)
```

Comment: Quita get y pon toSql() para que veas que consulta SQL se esta construyendo desde Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bajo este escenario, quizás la forma mas simple de construir la subconsulta que además viene acompañada de una **`unión`** de 2 **`select`** es aplicar alguno de los siguientes métodos que nos auxilian a pasar instrucciones en formato de SQL.

- `selectRaw`
- `whereRaw`
- etc.

Tomamos el segundo método para:

- Construir primero el `WHERE IN`
- Dentro en sentencia de SQL hacemos la subconsulta y la unión

Para este caso en específico una primer aproximación puede ser de esta forma:

```
DB::table('persona AS p')->select( 'p.nombre', 
                                   'p.apellidoPaterno',
                                   'p.apellidoMaterno',
                                   'p.genero',
                                   'p.fecha_nac',
                                   'p.pais_nac',
                                   'p.direccion',
                                   'p.correo',
                                   'p.telefono',
                                   'p.estado_civil',
                                   'p.nivel_educ',
                                   'p.profesion',
                                   'p.foto',
                                   'p.fecha_registro',
                                   'p.hora_registro'
                                 )->whereRaw('
                                                p.idPersona IN  (
                                                                    SELECT eu.idEmpleado FROM empleadousuario AS eu 
                                                                        UNION ALL 
                                                                    SELECT us.idUsuario FROM usuariosistema AS us
                                                                )
                                            ')->whereEstado('A')->get();
```

De esta forma:

- Evitas anidaciones extra
- Mantienes una lectura simple del código
- Te será fácil hacer modificaciones a tu **`UNION ALL`** por que la estructura esta sin modificaciones dentro de un solo método y no fragmentada en varios de ellos
- Puedes comprobar que la salida es la esperada, usando al final el método **`toSql()`**
  en sustitución del método **`get()`**
- Si necesitas pasar parámetros extra a tu subconsulta lo puedes hacer por medio de un array dentro del método **`whereRaw`** (*para esto lee la documentación*)

**Referencia**

- [Métodos raw del query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods)